# Command line output doesn't display version Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, command-line, python

I am trying to set up a virtual environment on my computer, however it doesnt seem to execute. I did the following:

```
C:\Users\frase\Desktop>python3 -m venv project_env
```

However the output was nothing. just went to the next line waiting for a command. However, there was a gap between them like so:

```
C:\Users\frase\Desktop>python3 -m venv project_env

C:\Users\frase\Desktop>
```

I than thought maybe python wasn't installed so i tried to check what version I have:

```
C:\Users\frase\Desktop>python3 --version

C:\Users\frase\Desktop>python3 -V
```

Again no output. The only command that works so far are "dir" and "cd" or moving along paths. Why is there no output being displayed?

Comment: Have your used the _py.exe_ launcher? Please see this page: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/interpreter.html#invoking-the-interpreter

Comment: run `where.exe python3` and check the output

Answer (score 0):

**Overview**

> Why is there no output being displayed?

If you wish to check if `python3` is available from the command line, you can try running `where python3`.

With that said, under Windows, `python3` is not typically used (`python3.exe` likely doesn't even exist). Using e.g. [vanilla Python for Windows](https://www.python.org/), `python` would generally be the way to call Python (assuming a `python.exe` executable was part of your Windows Path).

So, to check your python version, you would likely want to use e.g.:

```
python --version
```

or

```
python -V
```

**Other Methods of Calling Python**

As pointed out in the comment by @vssher, the [Python Launcher for Windows](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#python-launcher-for-windows) is another possible way to interact with Python on Windows (assuming it is installed). It is invoked as either simply `py` or e.g. `py -3.7` (or a similar variation, where the numbers following `py` are the preferred Python installation to use).

If you have multiple installations of Python, the Python Launcher for Windows has the advantage of being able to select Python versions other than whichever version might appear in your Windows Path. It also enables the use of [hash-bangs/shebangs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) in your Python scripts.

As a last resort, you can also use an absolute path to call a Python executable directly e.g. `C:\path\to\python.exe`.

**Virtual Environments**

> I am trying to set up a virtual environment on my computer, however it doesn't seem to execute.

While I believe you are having an issue, your experience with the virtual environment is expected behavior. That is, there should be no output (i.e. it should be just a "gap"). You can gauge the success of the command if a new folder corresponding to the name of your virtual environment is created in the directory where you ran the command.

Answer (score 0):

Same issue by me, turned out that the PATH environment variable was set to:
`%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python.exe`

Updating it to `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38` solved the issue.